# Работа с двумя списками в python (if, in, &)

Tags: python, if, for

Есть код:

```
test0 = [  ]
test1 = ['a1','a2','a3','b1','b2','b3','c1','c2','c3']

while True:
    p = str(input("Input: "))
    test0.append(p)
    if list(set(test0[-1]) & set(test1)):
        print('True')
    else:
        print('False')
```

Вывод:

```
Input: a1
False
Input: teat
False
Input: c1
False
Input: wtf?
False
Input:
```

Код должен показывать **True** при условии того, что значение **p** есть в словаре **test1**, но я где-то допустил ошибку. Ища ответ в интернете, не нашёл.

Можете показать мне где я так накосячил.

Comment: Сделайте `print( set(test0[-1]) )` и вы поймёте свою ошибку

Comment: andreymal, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Назовите переменные получше.

```
test = ['a1','a2','a3','b1','b2','b3','c1','c2','c3']
while True:
    variable = input("Input: ")
    if variable in test: #вот тут вы ошиблись. 
        print('True')
    else:
        print('False')
```

вывод:

```
Input: a1
True
Input: teat
False
Input: c1
True
Input: wtf?
False
```

Answer (score 1):

```
test0 = [  ]
test1 = ['a1','a2','a3','b1','b2','b3','c1','c2','c3']

while True:
    p = str(input("Input: "))
    test0.append(p)
    if p in test1:
        print('True')
    else:
        print('False')
```

Это должно работать.